# Crawlspace vapor barrier

Tags: crawlspace

I had vapor barrier installed in my crawlspace and it does not cover the perimeter drain. It only goes to the edge of the drain, about 8 inches away from the wall. Should it cover the drain and go up the wall?

Comment: The problem with covering the drain is that if you do get water in your crawl space, it's just going to sit on top of the plastic.

Comment: And how does water get into your crawl space?  Is it seepage though the foundation walls?

Comment: Thanks for the timely and insightful answers. Steve: The contractor voiced the same concern about moisture getting on top of the vapor barrier if the drains were covered. I'm getting a lot of opinions to cover the drain since water is coming from below, but I guess I have to trust the contractor's expertise and your advice
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Building science corporation recommends that crawl spaces should either be sealed in as part of the house, or sealed off from the house, so a partial seal is not ideal.
https://www.buildingscience.com/documents/building-science-insights-newsletters/bsi-115-crawlspaces-either-or-out

Comment: I'm not sure I would go so far as to say that a partial seal is not correct.  It may not be perfect or ideal, but it's better than a bare, probably damp floor.  Anything you can do to reduce the amount of moisture in the crawl space (at least in most areas of the country) is a plus, IMO.